# Convert PDF from Cloudinary to mail attachment Convert MemoryStream to Stream

Tags: asp.net, cloudinary

I am trying to convert a PDF that is stored on `Cloudinary` to a `System.Net.Mail Attachment` :

```
 private static Attachment CreateAttachementFromMessage(Stream stream)
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            return new Attachment(
                memoryStream,
                "Anhang zur Bestellung",
                "application/pdf"
                );
        }
```

the stream:

```
var stream = getFileStream(resourceId);
private getFileStream(resourceId){

                var imageData=_cloudinary.GetResource(resourceId);

                if (imageData.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var downloadUrl = _cloudinary.Api.UrlImgUp.Secure().BuildUrl(resourceId);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(downloadUrl))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return DownloadStream(new Uri(downloadUrl));}


}
```

The stream is not null but the mail content itself seems to be invalid.
File size is much smaller (factor 4) and cannot be opened.

Any ideas? Is there a problem with creating the stream, converting the stream or creating the attachment?

Edit: 
Copying the stream to memorystream:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IveNn.png

Edit 2: actual attachment content:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x85AO.png

Comment: Ah I think the problem is stream.Position beeing not 0

Comment: okay that wasn't it. please consider next screenshot displayiing actual attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody cares:

By converting via base64 it works fine:

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
                        String result = Convert.ToBase64String(binData);

                        var decodedFile = Convert.FromBase64String(result);

                        var mediaType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg).MediaType;

                        return new Attachment(
                            new MemoryStream(decodedFile),
                            $"Anhang zur Bestellung.{mediaType}",
                            mediaType
                        );
```

seems to be kind of unnecessary but method `stream.CopyTo()` ist not working for me